Adding validate-jwt policy fails on save when using Curity
We are using Curity as our identity management platform and are parsing the JWT token in Azure API Management using the validate-jwt policy. But suddenly, when we are trying to save changes in a policy that does this we get the error as shown here:

The policy does works on requests and validates the JWT token correctly, but it just fails on save.
Does anyone have any idea what the issue can be or how and where I can start investigate this further to get more information?

I've set up a stub service to return a "proper" OpenID response and pointed the openid-config URL in the JWT validation policy to the URL of this stub service - the policy was saved wihout any issue.
Then I modified the stub service response renaming one of the OpenID JSON fields: jwks_uri → jwks_uri1. After this change, saving the policy gave me the same error that you have:

It seems like the URL you are using returns a JSON that doesn't adhere to the OpenID schema.

Thought the same, but it has worked for some time now without any issues, this suddenly started now and the Curity installation is not changed since before this was set up. The validate-jwt policies in existing APIs are still working as well, but if I enter the editor I get the error there as well.. Is it so that Microsoft may have changed the validate-jwt policy, and if so is it any way to find this out?

I would have checked if the openid-configuration URL for some reason started returning a different response. Maybe you have another environment where everything still works so you can compare both JSONs. Regardless of whether the change was caused by Microsoft or by the Curity installation, you don't have control over what Microsoft might have done - you can only analyse the Curity side of things and try finding a workaround based on the data currently returned by the the openid-configuration URL.

I have several environments and all of them behaves exactly the same way :/ I dropped using openid-config and openid-configuration today and rather added the issuer-signing-key to go around the issue and I will report it as a support incident to Microsoft for aid...
